# PHP - How to get all string before the 3rd space character

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this :

$text = **"Hello, I'm just trying some stuff"**;

And I need to cut the string before the **third** space character, which would result as : **"Hello, I'm just"** in the end.

All I found so far is how to cut before the first occurence of a specific character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use explode to split by spaces, select just the first three (or fewer) elements, and then implode to reassemble just the ones I wanted.

```
$text = "Hello, I'm just trying some stuff";
$words = explode(' ', $text, 4);
$first_three = array_slice($words, 0, 3);
$output = implode(' ', $first_three);
```

A note that adding the last limit parameter to the explode function will prevent it from being too expensive in the case of a very large string. The remainder of the string will be put into the fourth, final element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just loop and maintain a count for a space. If count reaches 0, that index is your end limit for the `substr` function you can call. This also handles cases where the count you specify is more than the actual spaces itself.

```
<?php

$str = "Hello, I'm just trying some stuff";
$length = strlen($str);
$count = 3;
$index = $length;
for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i){
    if($str[$i] == ' '){
        $count--;
        if($count == 0){
            $index = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

}

echo substr($str, 0, $index);
```